# Is a model nested within itself before collapsing categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, regression-coefficients, nested-models

If I have a model with a categorical variable $X_1=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and a continuous variable $X_2$, and I have a regression model that includes an interaction between $X_1$ and $X_2$, then I decide I want to collapse $X_1$ into an indicator variable where $X_{1\text{_new}}=0$ if $X=0$ and $X_{1\text{_new}}=1$ if $X\ge1$, is my new model with an interaction term between $X_{1\text{_new}}$ and $X_2$ nested with the original model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is nested.  You could recreate the original data to have your x1_new variable and then additional dummy variables beyond x1_new, then the second model would just drop the additional dummy variables making those 2 models clearly nested.  Since the new full model would give an equivalent fit to the original full model you can treat your model as being nested in the original full model.